# Why am I not getting "main" updates?

Tags: apt, updates, software-updater

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 and since then I have the strong impression that I am not getting any update for the main packages.

In fact, since the upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 some 15 days ago, I run`sudo apt-get update` regularly and look at what packages are updated. Based on my experience with Ubuntu, I can tell I am getting updates only for PPAs (like Novacut) and Partner repositories (like Skype). I am not getting updates for other packages.

I don't get any error message when running  `sudo apt-get update`.
I am still able to install whatever I want with the Software Center or the command line.
Here is the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Alpha amd64 (20130402.1)]/ raring main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe
deb http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/ubuntu/ raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free #Spotify
# deb http://apt.last.fm/debian raring main #Last.fm disabled on upgrade to raring

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

How can I check whether my impression is correct? How do I correct the problem?

I tried deleting the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and then repopulating it automatically by running an update, but nothing changed.

Comment: The mirrors you are using might not be updated yet.  Not all mirrors are synced at the same time.

Comment: You haven't mentioned any reason why you think you aren't getting main updates.

Comment: Thank you @psusi , I edited the question to explain that I look at the update contents regularly and they seem to never be in the main repository, based on my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the software source from the local university one (Erlangen, see sources.list file) to the main German one. Now the Software Updater did download updates, including the kernel updates [rtmie](https://askubuntu.com/users/94122/rtmie) is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your sources.list looks similar to mine (which is a fresh install of raring).

From a terminal can you do :

sudo apt-get update|grep main

If apt is checking for updates on the main repo you should see lines like:
"Hit http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/ubuntu/ raring/main Translation-en" (Translation-en is an example there should be other lines as well)

If you do your updates from the command line (sudo apt-get dist-upgrade) you will where they are being pulled from.

For example this morning (May 4) there were kernel upgrades from main )

Comment: The output says `Hit http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/ubuntu/ raring/main Translation-en` indeed, but I did not get a kernel update. Not any update, in fact.